# Codename one Bar Chart

Tags: codenameone

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly sales in the last 1 years", "Cars", "sold", 0, 5, 0, 100, ColorUtil.GRAY, ColorUtil.LTGRAY);
renderer.setXLabels(1);
renderer.setYLabels(5);
renderer.setBarWidth(40);
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(8.0f);
```

Label text size is not rendering in Bar Charts?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the text size to 8 pixels which will make it pretty small and might not work if your fonts aren't native fonts. Try something like [this](http://You%20are%20setting%20the%20text%20size%20to%208%20pixels%20which%20will%20make%20it%20pretty%20small%20and%20might%20not%20work%20if%20your%20fonts%20aren't%20native%20fonts.).

```
renderer.setLabelsTextFont(Font.createTrueTypeFont("native:MainThin", "native:MainThin"));
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(convertToPixels(5));
```